# How i do custom Yii2 gridview sort?

Tags: php, datagrid, yii2

How can I sort with a customized `gridview` header?

Please give the difference between `label` and `header` in the `Yii2` `gridview` widget `dataprovider`.

Here is my code:

```php
    <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                 [
                   'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                   'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data->myTitle; 
                    },
                   'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
                   'header' => 'Page Title',
                   'label' => 'Title'
                ],
   ]); ?>
```

Do `header` and `label` perform the same function?

How can I perform sorting in `$data->myTitle`?

Here my Output Screen:

[image]

I want Page Title, Status, Date Modified should be active.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of data provider are you using?

Comment: @topherkanyuga i used ActiveData Provider.

Comment: Is myTiltle a custom value or a field in the database?

Comment: @topherkanyuga it's a field in my database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer.

Please add attributes to ActiveDataProvider in your Search Model.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 5,
                ],
        'sort' => ['attributes' => ['myTitle']],
       ]);
```

Add the attribute option in widget:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                 [
                   'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                   'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data->myTitle; 
                    },
                   'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
                   'attribute' => 'myTitle',
                   'label' => 'Page Title'
                ],
   ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `myTitle` is a field from the database and not a custom value, you can just use [attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$attribute-detail). The rest may be unnecessary e.g the default `class` is `DataColumn`

```
'columns' => [ 
    [ 
        'attribute' => 'myTitle',
        'label' => 'Label',
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure I understand your question, but sorting option can be included in your `modelsearch.php`. So in your case you have to do like this.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['your_column'=>SORT_ASC]]
        ]);
```

if `myTitle` is a field in the database, why you are using such a long syntax. Just

```
'Columns'=>[
           .. 
           'myTitle',
           ..
           ],
```

should work fine and should be active for sorting as you want

if you want a different header/label for the column, use label instead of header as header is only a cell content and cannot be used for sorting, while label can. [details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$header-detail)

```
[
..
'attribute'=>'myTitle',
'label' => 'Page Title'
..
],
```

Comment: Pls go through my output screen. Page title is a custom header, i need to active for sorting.