# sort link disappears when used 'value' tag in yii2 gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 Advanced Template. Below is code for generating Gridview widget on index page.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'invoice_id',
            [
                'label'=> 'Customer',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return ucfirst($model->customer->customer_name);
                },
                'enableSorting'=> TRUE,
            ],
            'invoice_type',
            'timestamp' => [
                'label' => 'Sale / Purchase Date',
                'attribute' => 'timestamp',
                'format' => ['date', 'php:y-m-d h:i:s A'],
            ],
            'payment_option',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template'=>'{view} {delete}'],
        ],
    ]); 
?>
```

The problem is, despite using 'label' and 'enableSorting' for 'customer_name' when I use 'value' property, the Sort link Disappears. How to enable Sort link. Also attaching snapshot of my view;

[image: SNAPSHOT]

After Solving the issue, when I click the sort link, i get below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this column configuration like this:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'customer.customer_name',
    'label'=> 'Customer',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return ucfirst($model->customer->customer_name);
    },
],
```

Comment: You won't believe! I tried immediately after posting this issue. It still remains the same :(

Comment: You may also need to set the `sort` attribute of the `dataProvider` you are using for Grid View. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936787/how-i-do-custom-yii2-gridview-sort - the accepted answer shows how to set the `sort` attribute

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot, the post you shared also gave me some insight! Thanks a ton again. Cheers!

Comment: But, I get another issue when i try to sort as per 'Customer' Column. You can refer to updated post above.

Comment: @AnkurSoni. Add `searchModel`.