# Yii2 gridview sort custom column

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a poll in my project.In grid I have show the count.

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'label' =>"Constituency",
        'attribute' => 'constituency',
        'value'=>function($data){
            return $data["constituency"];
        }
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
        'label' =>"Count",
        'attribute' => 'count',
       'value'=>function($data){
            return $data->getCount($data["constituency"]);
        },
        'enableSorting'=>TRUE ,

    ],

],
```

**My Model**
for get count

```
    public static  function  getCount($constituency){
    $cat = Polls::find()->where(['poll_place'=>$constituency])->count();
    // $cat = ArrayHelper::map($cat, 'id', 'name');
    return $cat;
}
```

The count column is a custom column.
Can anyone help to sort that column.
I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956638/how-to-sort-custom-columns-in-gridview-widget-in-yii-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936787/how-i-do-custom-yii2-gridview-sort/27958666).
Both are failed because my **count** attribute is not in my DB.
Showing the following error
[image: Database Error]

Comment: I can help you here but need some more information. Can you please show the code for `getCount()`?

Comment: What do you wish to get the count of, exactly?

Comment: update your question and add  the code related  to count .. model or searchModel ..

Comment: i have updated the question...

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is done at SQL level, you cannot blindly allow sorting on virtual attribute, you need to adapt your query to handle such sorting.

First, you need to add proper [relation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#hasMany()-detail) between two models. In your `Constituency` model add something like:

```
public function getPools()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Pools::className(), ['pool_place' => 'constituency']);
}
```

Then join two tables in query and enable grouping, so you can be able to calculate `count` for each `Constituency`.

```
$query = Constituency::find()->joinWith('pools')->groupBy('constituency');
```

Then configure sorting:

```
$sort = new Sort([
    'attributes' => [
        'constituency',
        'count' => [
            'asc' => 'COUNT(pools.poll_place) ASC',
            'desc' => 'COUNT(pools.poll_place) DESC',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

You may also create `count` attribute in your `Constituency` and add `->addSelect(['count' => Expression('COUNT(pools.poll_place)')])` to your query, to avoid excessive queries for polls count for each `Constituency`.